# mongodb - thread over memory limit

Tags: mongodb, linux, memory

What does it mean?

2017-04-28T04:37:53.126+0000 D -        [conn1571] thread over memory limit, cleaning up, current: 67k
2017-04-28T04:37:53.911+0000 D -        [conn1585] thread over memory limit, cleaning up, current: 79k

Should I make something to solve it? If I increas server memory will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/util/tcmalloc_server_status_section.cpp) code:

```
// If many clients are used, the per-thread caches become smaller and chances of
// rebalancing of free space during critical sections increases. In such situations,
// it is better to release memory when it is likely the thread will be blocked for
// a long time.
```

And when numOpenSessions is over 40 and threadCacheSizeBytes (GetThreadCacheSize()) goes under 0x10000, system frees memory.

So, to "prevent" this, you should have less (concurrent) open sessions OR more (cache) memory. You can define (wiredTiger) bigger (than default) cache size, with current memory. But, yes, it's better give more memory than define bigger cache size, because when mongodb have more memory, cache size is automatically bigger.

Comment: I upgraded server twice. Server had 16G. Now it have 30G. I see same messages.

Comment: db.serverStatus().storageEngine
MongoDB server version: 3.4.3
> db.serverStatus().storageEngine
{
        "name" : "mmapv1",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : true
}

Comment: What db.serverStatus().connections says. Remember that every connection eat 1MB memory.

Comment: > db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 145, "available" : 51055, "totalCreated" : 200 }

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-124 ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         30667      20658      10008          0        150      19187
-/+ buffers/cache:       1320      29347

Comment: Is there good reason to use mmapv1 and not wiredTiger? Would it be possible to you change it?

Comment: DB have 1TB of data. It is too long to backup it and restore again. It will take near 3 days. Is it possible to fix without chaging engine? There was no result after incrice twice of memory.

Comment: At my daily job I take care of big cluster where every node have 1,5TB (compressed; uncompressed size is MUCH bigger) data and I would not even DREAM to run that only 30GB memory... We use 120GB, but have tested with 64GB.. Yes, it worked, but performance was not good enough. When that data was mmapv1, we had 512GB memory and that was not enough for smooth operation.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will think how to move data to wiredTiger.

Comment: If it's replica set (hope so), just replicate it to wiredTiger secondary node.

Comment: It's not replica set. Could I switch to replica set my db using restart with --replSet rs_name arg? Is it good way for existed db?

Comment: Yes, you can. No, problem. Start with --replSet, then log in (with mongo) and give command rs.initiate() and you have one node replica set. With command rs.add("address:port") you can then add new wiredTiger node. After replication is over, move primary to that node, log in (that new node), use rs.remove("adddress:port") to remove mmapv1 node, poit your clients to this new one node replica set, if you want still keep only one node.